# Is valid return local object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function makeCar() {
    var car = {
        color: "red",
        convertible: true
    };

    return car;
}
```

I know that local variable `car` holds a reference to the object, but when the function finish, will the object be released resulting in memory leak?

Comment: The object will only be released if there are no references to it.  What would you expect `var x = makeCar()` to do?

Comment: JS is a garbage-collected language. Memory does not get allocated by assignment/initialisation, and is not released just because something goes out of scope.

Comment: memory is released by the garbage-collector only when there are no references to the object, yet there are some exceptions like `WeakMap` and `WeakSet`

Comment: Of course you can use this. The caller receives a "copy" of `car`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Life of JavaScript objects & Memory Leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114851/life-of-javascript-objects-memory-leaks)